# plotting after solve does not display anything

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, functions, variable-definitions

I'm quite new to Mathematica language,
I am trying to figure out where I am making mistakes in Plotting a specific function that depends to other variables:

I want to plot

```
   Manipulate[Plot[{Im[fxDBL[φW, Λg]], 
   Im[fyDBL[φW, Λg]]}, {φW, 19, 
   23}], {Λg, 1.800, 2.500}]
```

I am defining the function fxDBL as

```
solution = Solve[φrad == π/2 + 1/2 (-π + aa - bb) + bb, aa];

fun = TrigExpand[Λg*λ/nres == Sin[aa - φrad] + Sin[bb + φrad]] /. solution[[1]] // Simplify;

solution2 = bb /. Solve[fun, bb] /. C[1] -> 1;

fxDBL[φW_,Λg_]:= ArcSin[nres*Sin[φW*π/180 - solution2[[2]]]]*180/π /. φrad -> φW* π/180;
```

but nothing is displayed...
even if.., if I copy the final numerical output and defining fxDBL as

```
fxDBL[φW_, Λg_] := (
  180 ArcSin[
    1.49` Sin[(π φW)/180 - 
       ArcCos[0.17852348993288591` Λg Csc[(π \
φW)/180]]]])/π;
```

Mathematica plots correctly the function I need.

what am I missing? is it something related to the output of Solve that is not used properly with solution2[[2]]?
Thank you

Comment: In your code here, `λ` and `nres` are not defined, but I assume they are equal to 0.532 and 1.49?

Comment: How is `fyDBL[φW, Λg]` in `Manipulate` defined? The code doesn't work even if you delete it, but the definition is missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you make the substitution `/. φrad -> φW* π/180`, the term `φrad` doesn't appear in the expression to the left.  You can solve this in two ways, either use `Set` instead of `SetDelayed`,

```
fxDBL[φW_, Λg_] = 
 ArcSin[
     nres*Sin[φW*π/180 - 
        solution2[[2]]]]*180/π /. φrad -> φW* π/180
```

or use `Evaluate`,

```
fxDBL[φW_, Λg_] := 
 Evaluate[ArcSin[
     nres*Sin[φW*π/180 - 
        solution2[[2]]]]*180/π /. φrad -> φW* π/180]
```

Now your `Manipulate` works fine (assuming you define `fyDBL` at some point as well)

[image]

**Edit**

If you want to export your `Manipulate` as a gif animation, the non-intuitive way to do it is to export first as a movie, import that movie and export as a gif.

```
ManToGif[man_, name_String, step_Integer: 1] := 
 Module[{moviename}, 
  moviename = 
   name <> If[$OperatingSystem === "MacOSX", ".mov", ".avi"];
  Export[name <> ".gif", 
   Import[Export[moviename, man], "ImageList"][[1 ;; -1 ;; step]]];
  DeleteFile[moviename];]
```

This was adapted from [Vitaliy's post](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/86994) on the community

Comment: May I ask how you made the movie of the manipulate window? What do you use?

Comment: @Moo - that is one of my new favorite functions.  I'm using the `ManToGif` function defined [here](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/86994)

Comment: Any ideas (cut and pasted his example) and get StringJoin::string: String expected at position 2 in charge<>Which[OperatingSystem==MacOSX,.mov,OperatingSystem==Windows,.avi]. >>

Export::chtype: First argument charge<>Which[OperatingSystem==MacOSX,.mov,OperatingSystem==Windows,.avi] is not a valid file specification. >>

Import::chtype: First argument $Failed is not a valid file, directory, or URL specification. >>

Symbol::argx: Symbol called with 0 arguments; 1 argument is expected. >>

Comment: @Moo - try the updated code I posted here instead